# How to extract the first three segments of an IP address in android

Tags: java, android, regex, ip

Example:

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is an IP address format and I want to get only the first three segments (with dots): xxx.xxx.xxx.

Another example:

192.168.0.160 and I want only 192.168.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] splittedArray = ipAddressString.split("\\.");
String firstThreeSegments = splittedArray [0] + "." + splittedArray [1] + "." + splittedArray [2] + ".";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I will try the code as soon as return home and I will inform you.

Comment: Take a look at documentation of `split` method, or simply run your code before you post it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I really didn't know that. This should work now.

Answer (score 4):

```
String partialIp = ipAddress.substring(0, ipAddress.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String#replaceFirst`

```
String firstThree = ip.replaceFirst("\\d+$", "");
```

This will replace any valid IP address's last part and replace it by empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mO3zW1/2)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest method (IMO) would be to use (from Apache Commons) [`StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)  to find the index value of the third period, and then use `substring()` to take the substring from 0 to that index value. 
**For instance:**

```
StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf("192.168.0.160", ".", 3)  == 9
```

Then you can use this index to take a substring.

Comment: No worries. If you find this solution helpful an upvote is always nice!